# cross compile with 32b and 64b

Tags: compilation, ubuntu-12.04, cross-compiling, apt-get, openwrt

I cross-compile OpenWRT in 64b and now I need to add some package (not from community) that forced to be compiled in 32b.
My problem is that the openwrt (64b) require "libssl-dev" and the new package (32b) require "libssl-dev:i386" and therefore I need each time to install the suit library before compiling the code.

Is there a way that they will co-exists  and I could compile the new package as part of the openwrt without installing "libssl-dev" "libssl-dev:i386" alternating?

background details:
I use Ubuntu 12.04 as my development machine.

comment:
i see that there is allegedly a bug fix but it is still removing "libssl-dev" once installing "libssl-dev:i386"

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=689093

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to overcome this problem:

1. upgrade to UBUNTU 15 - the problem is solved in this UBUNTU version.
2. create a local folder with the headers and content of libssl-dev:i368 and compile with the local copy.